# Expected Optimism 0-1 Loss with 0-1 Response

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, expected-value, covariance, optimism

**Want to show that**
$$ E_X op = \frac{2}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n Cov_X(g(x_i), Y_i)$$

For 0-1 loss function with 0-1 response.

**Want I've done**

$$op = l_{in}(g) - l(g)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1} ^n Loss(Y_i', g(x_i ))-\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1} ^n Loss(Y_i, g(x_i ))$$ 
where each response $Y_i'$ is drawn as a random sample from the density function.
$$Loss(Y_i', g(x_i)) = \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 \; \; \; \, , \; if\;  Y_i \neq g(x_i) \\
0 \; \; \; \, , \; if\;  Y_i = g(x_i)
\end{matrix}\right.$$
given that 
$E_X op = E [op | X_1 = x_1, ..., X_n = x_n]$ where $E$ is the expected value

$$E_X op = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1} ^n E \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 \; \; \; \, , \; if\;  Y_i' \neq g(x_i) \\
0 \; \; \; \, , \; if\;  Y_i' = g(x_i)
\end{matrix}\right. -\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1} ^n E \left\{\begin{matrix}
1 \; \; \; \, , \; if\;  Y_i \neq g(x_i) \\
0 \; \; \; \, , \; if\;  Y_i = g(x_i)
\end{matrix}\right.$$

I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're reading DSML, then I think you can just use the result they proved in the text for squared-error loss: note that $\mathbb{1}[Y_i \neq \hat{Y}_i] = (Y_i - \hat{Y}_i)^2$ when $Y_i, \hat{Y}_i \in \{0,1\}$.